# Generating a 2 variables polynomial with constraints

Tags: function-construction, summation, polynomials, constraint, expression-construction

I would like to generate automatically a polynomial in two variables $(s,t)$ which is symmetric under the exchange of those variables. There are three kinds of terms; at order $k$, we have
$$(s+t)^k, \quad (st)^k, \quad (s+t)^a(st)^b,$$
where $a+b=k$. Using a simple sum it is not difficult to write down in Mathematica the first two types. If "ord" is the degree of the polynomial, I just define a function $poly[s,t,ord]$ as
$$\sum_{i=0}^{ord} \big( c_i(s+t)^i +d_i(st)^i \big),$$
where $c_i,d_i$ are some coefficients.

But how can I generate the third type?

Comment: But the degree of `(s+t)^k` is `k` and the degree of `(st)^k` is `2k` and the degree of `(s+t)^a (st)^b` is `a+2b`, what is the order do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one running index: k and a second running index: a for a=0..k. b will then be k-a. With this e.g:

```
ord=3;
Sum[Subscript[c, a, i - a] (s + t)^a (s t)^(i - a), {i, 0, ord}, {a, 0, i}]
```

[image]